# Надпись не изменяется по нажатию на кнопку в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Если выбираем '+1' то к единице прибавляется 1, если(x2) то к единица умножается на два. но функция не работает

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

def event():
    a=int(lab['text'])
    if 1==i.get():
        a+=1
    elif i.get()==2:
        a*=1    


lab=Label(root,text='1')
lab.grid(row=0,column=0)

but=Button(root,text='Действие',command=event)
but.grid(row=1,column=0)

i =IntVar()
i.set(1)

i1=Radiobutton(root,text='+1',variable=i,value=1)
i1.grid(row=0,column=1)

i2=Radiobutton(root,text='x2',variable=i,value=2)
i2.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обновляйте текст в `label` и как по мне умножение числа на 1 не дает сильного результата

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

def event():
    a=int(lab['text'])
    if 1==i.get():
        a+=1
    elif i.get()==2:
        a*=2
    lab["text"] = a


lab=Label(root,text='1')
lab.grid(row=0,column=0)

but=Button(root,text='Действие',command=event)
but.grid(row=1,column=0)

i =IntVar()
i.set(1)

i1=Radiobutton(root,text='+1',variable=i,value=1)
i1.grid(row=0,column=1)

i2=Radiobutton(root,text='x2',variable=i,value=2)
i2.grid(row=1,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное